# How to return to app after starting activity with intent?

Tags: android, calendar

From my Android app, I want to be able to show the native event creation screen and when the user presses "Done", the event is created and I want to automatically return to my app. Instead what happens right now, is that the native Calendar app is opened and the user has to press the back button to return to my app.

This is my code:

```
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "New event");
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, new Date().getTime());
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("onActivityResult!");
}
```

Also, `onActivityResult(...)` is never called. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `ACTION_EDIT` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`, as [it does not return anything](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EDIT).

Beyond that, the decision of what do when the user completes editing a calendar event is up to the implementers of the calendar app. You are delegating work to a third-party app; what the third-party app does is up to its developers. This is no different than linking your Web site to somebody else's Web site: you do not choose what that Web site does.

Furthermore, there is no single "the native Calendar app". There are thousands of Android device models, and in principle they can ship with whatever they want. That includes having zero, one, or several activities that respond to your `Intent`. Devices that have the Play Store *probably* have Google Calendar installed, but not necessarily, and the user may use some other calendar app (e.g., one they installed from the Play Store or elsewhere). So, not only is the decision of what to do when the user completes editing the calendar entry up to the calendar app's developers, but there are many calendar apps, each with their own developers and own decisions to make in this area.

When you launch a third-party app, do not make many assumptions about the resulting navigation flow. If you need that degree of control, in this case, you would have to write your own calendar functionality and bake it into your app.

Comment: Did I mention I do not have much experience with intents? Haha. Thank you for your fast answer. Is there by any chance a way to open up the default calendar entry screen without using intents? I would probably have to start looking for a default open source component that does this.

Comment: @TomvanZummeren: "Is there by any chance a way to open up the default calendar entry screen without using intents?" -- there is no "default calendar entry screen".

Comment: Actually I come from iOS, and I was simply looking for an equivalent of the EKEventEditViewController, but I guess there isn't such a thing on Android.

Comment: @TomvanZummeren: If you are trying to show a calendar, for the purpose of picking a date, there is `CalendarView`. There is nothing in Android for editing calendar entries directly, any more than there is something in Android for washing dishes. From Android's standpoint, editing calendar entries is what calendar apps do, and so your `Intent` is the closest analogue. But, you are launching a separate app for this, and so YMMV.